# Datatable not correctly select checkboxes using Primeng and Angular 14

Tags: angular, primeng

I have a problem when selecting the elements of my table. Every time I select the elements the ones in the second column are automatically selected.
The same happens when I select some checkbox in the row or in the other column and selected.

What I would like is that when clicking on the checkbox, the one in the other column is not selected.
Same thing if you select the checkbox to mark all items in the column, those in the other column should not be filled in automatically.

Ts

```
selectAll(cars: CarDTO[], check: any) {
    if (check) {
      this.carSelected = cars.filter(p => p.changeValue === false);
    } else {
      check= false;
      this.carSelected = [];
    }

  }



checkYear(car: CarDTO) {
    if (!car.updateValue) {
      car.updateValue= true;
    } else {
      car.updateValue = true;
    }
  }

check(car: CarDTO) {
    if (!car.updateYear) {
      car.updateYear= true;
    } else {
      car.updateYear= true;
    }
  }
```

Page html

```
<p-table [value]="cars" responsiveLayout="scroll" 
                                    styleClass="p-datatable-striped" 
                                    [resizableColumns]="true" [autoLayout]="true"
                                    [(selection)]="carSelected">
                                <ng-template pTemplate="header">
                                    <tr>
                                        <!-- <th rowspan="3">
                                            <p-tableHeaderCheckbox></p-tableHeaderCheckbox>
                                        </th> -->
                                        <th rowspan="30"><span style="float: right">Id</span></th>
                                        <th rowspan="3"><span style="float: left">Name</span></th>
                                        <th rowspan="3"><span style="float: right">Color</span></th>
                                    </tr>
                                    <tr>
                                        <th colspan="3" style="text-align: center;">Year</th>
                                        <th colspan="3" style="text-align: center;">Model</th>
                          </tr>
                                    <tr>
                                        <th><span style="float: right">Current</span></th>
                                        <th><span style="float: right">Last</span></th>
                                        <th>
                                            <p-tableHeaderCheckbox (click)="selectAll(car, current.checked)" #current></p-tableHeaderCheckbox>
                                        </th>
                                        <th><span style="float: right">Current</span></th>
                                        <th><span style="float: right">Last</span></th>
                                        <th>
                                          <p-tableHeaderCheckbox (click)="selectAll(car, current.checked)" #current></p-tableHeaderCheckbox>
                                        </th>
                                      </tr>
                                </ng-template>
                                <ng-template pTemplate="body" let-car>
                                    <tr>
                                        <td><span style="float: right">{{car.id}}</span></td>
                                        <td><span style="float: left">{{car.name}}</span></td>
                                        <td><span style="float: right">{{car.color}}</span></td>
                                        <td><span style="float: right">
                                            {{car.current}}</span></td>
                                        <td>{{car.last}}</span></td>
                                        <td>
                                            <p-tableCheckbox name="current" [value]="produto" (click)="check(car)"></p-tableCheckbox>
                                        </td>
                            <td><span style="float: right">
                                            {{car.currentYear}}</span></td>
                                        <td>{{car.lastYear}}</span></td>
                                        <td>
                                            <p-tableCheckbox name="model" [value]="car" (click)="checkYear(car)"></p-tableCheckbox>
                                        </td>

                            <td><span style="float: right">
                                            {{car.currentModel}}</span></td>
                                        <td>{{car.lastModel}}</span></td>
                                        <td>
                                            <p-tableCheckbox name="current" [value]="car" (click)="checkModel(car)"></p-tableCheckbox>
                                        </td>
                                    </tr>
                                </ng-template>
                            </p-table>
```

Answer (score 0):

You are missing attribute `dataKey="id"` of `p-table`.

Comment: I entered the id as explained. However, it continues to select all the other checkboxes in the other columns and not just the one in the first column